# Can you diff all files in one directory?

Tags: command-line, files, diff

I have a bunch of files stored in various directories. They have been created at different times, but I need to check that their contents are the same. I cannot find how to do a `diff` on ALL files in one directory. Is this possible or is another CLI tool required?

Comment: Related question/answers on stackoverflow: [how to compare more than 2 files at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need to compare them, and only need to know *if* they differ, you can just diff every file in the directory with any one of the files in the directory via a for-loop...

`for i in ./*; do diff -q "$i" known-file; done`

...where `known-file` is just any given file in the directory. If you get no output, none of the files differ; else you'll get a list of the files that differ from `known-file`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the standard `cksum` utility along with `awk`:

```
find . -type f -exec cksum {} + | awk '!ck[$1$2]++ { print $3 }'
```

The `cksum` utility will output three columns for each file in the current directory.  The first is a checksum, the second is a file size, and the third is a filename.

The `awk` program will create an array, `ck`, keyed on the checksum and size.  If the key does not already exist, the filename is printed.

This means that you get the filenames in the current directory that have unique checksums + size. If you get more than one filename, then these two have different checksums and/or size.

Testing:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Oct  3 16:32 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Oct  3 16:32 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  6 Oct  3 16:32 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  0 Oct  3 16:32 file4
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  kk  6 Oct  3 16:34 file5

$ find . -type f -exec cksum {} + | awk '!ck[$1$2]++ { print $3 }'
./file1
./file3
```

The files `file1`, `file2` and `file4` are all empty, but `file3` and `file5` have some content.  The command shows that there are two sets of files: Those that are the same as `file1` and those that are the same as `file3`.

We may also see exactly what files are the same:

```
$ find . -type f -exec cksum {} + | awk '{ ck[$1$2] = ck[$1$2] ? ck[$1$2] OFS $3 : $3 } END { for (i in ck) print ck[i] }'
./file3 ./file5
./file1 ./file2 ./file4
```

Comment: This seems to fail if the folder names have spaces in them? OP's files are in "various subfolders"

Comment: @CPBL So it is. It is now two years later and I will look at this in due time.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of files in directory d, here are results for 4 codes that look for duplicate files:

```
Environment: LC_ALL = C, LANG = C
(Versions displayed with local utility "version")
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
fdupes 1.51
jdupes 1.5.1 (2016-11-01)
rdfind 1.3.4
duff 0.5.2

-----
 Files in directory d:
==> d/f1 <==
1

==> d/f11 <==
1

==> d/f2 <==
2

==> d/f20 <==
Now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their country.

==> d/f21 <==
Now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their country.

==> d/f22 <==
Now is the time
for all good men
to come to the aid
of their countryz

==> d/f3 <==
1


-----
 Results for fdupes:
d/f1                                    
d/f3
d/f11

d/f20
d/f21


-----
 Results for jdupes:
Examining 7 files, 1 dirs (in 1 specified)
d/f1                                                        
d/f3
d/f11

d/f20
d/f21

-----
 Results for rdfind:
Now scanning "d", found 7 files.
Now have 7 files in total.
Removed 0 files due to nonunique device and inode.
Now removing files with zero size from list...removed 0 files
Total size is 218 bytes or 218 b
Now sorting on size:removed 0 files due to unique sizes from list.7 files left.
Now eliminating candidates based on first bytes:removed 1 files from list.6 files left.
Now eliminating candidates based on last bytes:removed 1 files from list.5 files left.
Now eliminating candidates based on md5 checksum:removed 0 files from list.5 files left.
It seems like you have 5 files that are not unique
Totally, 74 b can be reduced.
Now making results file results.txt

-----
 Results for duff:
3 files in cluster 1 (2 bytes, digest e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e)
d/f1
d/f3
d/f11
2 files in cluster 2 (70 bytes, digest 7de790fbe559d66cf890671ea2ef706281a1017f)
d/f20
d/f21
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

You may also try GUI tool meld.

```
meld dir1 dir2
```

or

```
meld dir1 dir2 dir3
```

https://meldmerge.org/help/command-line.html

Comment: Thanks but it has to be CLI. Maybe I'll just write a script to put filenames into an array and try it that way. I was hoping for a simpler solution though! lol

Comment: OK, I've also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787916/difference-between-two-directories-in-linux It's probably what you're looking for.