# Bash command to list all files based on content

Tags: bash, shell

What I am trying to accomplish is to take all files in a directory and list / sort them by uniqueness of their content

Example:

Say we have these 7 files in a directory

```
uniquefile1.txt, uniquefile2.txt, samefile1.txt, samefile2.txt, equalfile1.txt, equalfile2.txt, equalfile3.txt
```

where uniquefile1 and uniquefile2 have different content, all samefile.txt's have the same content as each other, and all equalfile.txt's have the same content as each other

Expected output:

```
uniquefile1.txt
uniquefile2.txt
samefile1.txt, samefile2.txt
equalfile1.txt, equalfile2.txt, equalfile3.txt
```

I have been messing around with hashing and using md5sum, but have not been able to get anything to accomplish exactly that

I want to accomplish this using utilities like grep, xargs, sed, awk, find, and locate mixed with some other coreutils if necessary.

Comment: and how unique files with different names should be sorted? I.e. what if there `reg-file.txt` , `somefile.txt`

Comment: Does not matter

Comment: `md5sum * | sort` is not quite what you are asking for, but it is simple and it will bring groups of identical files together - which is often all one needs - but it does need postprocessing to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified part of [an answer I wrote yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395863/116858):

```
$ cksum file* | awk '{ ck[$1$2] = ck[$1$2] ? ck[$1$2] ", " $3 : $3 } END { for (i in ck) print ck[i] }'
file3, file5
file1, file2, file4
```

In your case you would use `*.txt` or even `*` (if all you have in the directory are the file you'd like to compare) rather than `file*`.

The result tells us that `file3` and `file5` have the same contents, as does `file1`, `file2`, and `file4` (in this example).

The standard `cksum` utility will output three columns for each file. The first is a checksum, the second is a file size, and the third is a filename.

The `awk` code will use the checksum and size as a key in the array `ck` and store the filenames that have the same key in a comma-separated string for that key. At the end, the filenames (comma-separated string) are printed out.

The funny looking

```
ck[$1$2] = ck[$1$2] ? ck[$1$2] ", " $3 : $3
```

just means "if `ck[$1$2]` is set to anything, then assign `ck[$1$2] ", " $3` to `ck[$1$2]` (appending a filename with a comma in-between), otherwise just assign `$3` (it's the first filename with this key)".

---

To sort the output on the number of items in each list, pass the output through

```
awk -F, '{ print NF, $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

... as a post-processing stage. This will obviously break if any filename contains a comma.

Or use

```
cksum file* | awk '{ n[$1$2]++; ck[$1$2] = ck[$1$2] ? ck[$1$2] ", " $3 : $3 } END { for (i in ck) print n[i], ck[i] }' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

which does not have any issues with commas in filenames.

Leave the `cut` out if you'd like to see the number of filenames on each line of output.

---

For a huge number of files, you may want to use

```
find . -type f -exec cksum {} +
```

rather than just

```
cksum *
```

Comment: Instead of just listing them in the order they are checked, how would I go about sorting them in order from unique files to largest group of same files

Comment: @Hopsain See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -MDigest::SHA -le '
  for $f (@ARGV) {
    $d = Digest::SHA->new(256);
    $d->addfile($f);
     push @{$h{$d->digest}}, $f
  }
  print join ", ", @{$h{$_}} for keys %h' -- *.txt
```

We're building an associative array whose keys are the sha256 hash of the files and the value the list of files with that hash.

It makes it easy to sort the output by number of occurrences for instance with:

```
perl -MDigest::SHA -le '
  for $f (@ARGV) {
    $d = Digest::SHA->new(256);
    $d->addfile($f);
     push @{$h{$d->digest}}, $f
  }
  print join ", ", @{$h{$_}} for sort {@{$h{$a}} <=> @{$h{$b}}} keys %h' -- *.txt
```

Or even sort the list of files in each set by file name:

```
perl -MDigest::SHA -le '
  for $f (@ARGV) {
    $d = Digest::SHA->new(256);
    $d->addfile($f);
     push @{$h{$d->digest}}, $f
  }
  print join ", ", sort {$a cmp $b} @{$h{$_}} for 
    sort {@{$h{$a}} <=> @{$h{$b}}} keys %h' -- *.txt
```